# Using $in inside $cond in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use `$in` inside `$cond` but it's not working as expecting for some reason. Here is the my code:

```
{
  $project: {
   'profile': 1,
   'isFollowing': {
      $cond: [{
        $in: ['$profile','$following.followingProfiles']
      },true, false]
    },
      'following':1
    }
}
```

And here is what returns

```
[
   {
     "profile": "5f11fffea15f9631a4de850f",
        "following": [
          {
            "followingProfiles": [
               "5f11fffea15f9631a4de850f"
            ]
          }
      ],
      "isFollowing": false
   }
]
```

But `isFollowing` attribute should be true, not false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error $following.followingProfiles isn't an object, but an array of object notice

```
following": [{
    "followingProfiles": [
       "5f11fffea15f9631a4de850f"
    ]
  }
],
```

So I made following an object using `$set` as follows

```
$set: { following:{ $arrayElemAt: ['$following', 0] } }
```

and this solved it.